# powershell implement progressbar for filtered dirs

Tags: powershell

I created a script to copy file and dir/subdir in Powershell that works well.
Now I would like to try to implement it with a progressbar.
My directory structure is made in this way

```
test / dirfoo / file1, file2, subdir1, subdir2, ..  
     / dirbar / file1, file2, subdir1, subdir2, ..
     / @dirfoo / file1, file2, subdir1, subdir2, ..
     / @dirbar / file1, file2, subdir1, subdir2, ..
     / file1
     / file2
     / ..
```

SCRIPT

```
Function Copy-WithProgress
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
        Position=0)]
    $Source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
        Position=0)]
    $Destination
)

$Source=$Source.tolower()
$Filelist=Get-Childitem "$Source" –Recurse
$Total=$Filelist.count
$Position=0

foreach ($File in $Filelist)
{
    $Filename=$File.Fullname.tolower().replace($Source,'')
    $DestinationFile=($Destination+$Filename)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying data from '$source' to '$Destination'" -Status "Copying 
    File $Filename" -PercentComplete (($Position/$total)*100)
    Copy-Item $File.FullName -Destination $DestinationFile
    $Position++
  }
 }

 $syncSource=c:\test
 $syncDest=d:\test

 Copy-WithProgress -Source $syncSource -Destination $syncDest
```

Now I would like to try to copy only the subdir and their files that have the character @ at the beginning of the name

To filter the names I usually make this way but I can't implement it in the copy-withprogress function

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $modSource | 
Where-Object { $_.Name -match '@' } | 
Copy-Item -Destination $modDest -Recurse -Force
```

How could I do?
Thanks

Comment: please understand that the `Write-Progress` cmdlet is SO VERY SLOW that it is one of the 1st things one is recommended to _disable_ when code is reported to be "too slow". if you MUST have some sort of activity indicator, just output a counter something like `$CurCount of $TotalCount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the final call to `Copy-Item` with `ForEach-Object` so you can call `Write-Progress` immediately prior to copying:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $modSource |
Where-Object { $_.Name -match '@' } |
ForEach-Object {
  Write-Progress -Status "Progress status message goes here" ...
  $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $modDest -Recurse -Force
}
```

---

If you simply wish to add optional name-based filtering to the existing function, do the following:

Add a `-Filter` parameter:

```
param(
    ...,

    [string]$Filter = '*'
)
```

And then change the statement where you resolve the file list to use the filter:

```
$Filelist = Get-Childitem "$Source" –Recurse |Where-Object { $_.Name -like $Filter }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in this way the progress bar does not advance

Comment: @PaoloRossi No, you need to provide a percentage for that. If you want to report the total percentage of "files starting with @" for example, you'll have to split the operation into two separate steps: 1) enumerate files and filter with `Where-Object`, 2) count resulting files and write progress with exact percentage before copying.

Comment: Ok, but how could I implement it in the Copy-Withprogress function? Should I add a parameter to differentiate the type of simple copy and with a filter? Thanks a lot

Comment: @PaoloRossi Sorry, I thought you were asking about the `Write-Progress` call. For filtering, simply add a `[string]$Filter` parameter with a default value of `'*'`, then change `$Filelist=Get-Childitem "$Source" –Recurse` to `$Filelist=Get-Childitem "$Source" –Recurse |Where-Object Name -like $Filter`. Then you can invoke with `Copy-WithProgress $source $destination -Filter '@*'`

Comment: Thanks, what I was looking for. I try it immediately.

Comment: You can add the code in your answer, so I accept the answer. This will help someone in the future. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to modify how you suggested to me but I don't copy them to tell them

Comment: I don't understand why I see that I filter the @dir but then I don't copy them in the destination.

Comment: @PaoloRossi Are you by any chance suppressing errors (eg. `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Ignore'` or similar)? I'd expect it to fail because the destination directory doesn't exist

Comment: I've this error. +  Copy-WithProgress $source $destination -Filter '@*'
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-WithProgress], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousPositionalParameterNoName,Copy-WithProgress

Comment: @PaoloRossi That indicates you didn't actually define the `$Filter` parameter correctly